# Is there a maximum execution time on some Apple devices for main thread activities?

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, ipad

I've an iOS app that collects some local data and compiles all that data in a PDF on request.

My problem is one customer uses a iPad Mini (32 Bit CPU) and the mentioned PDF export crashes the app. I tried to reproduce the issue with his SQLite database. I imported his database in my App, but I was not able to reproduce the crash. However I've only 64 Bit hardware and Simulator available, no real iPad Mini 1st Gen.

However I noticed I did accidently execute the PDF export in the main thread. (UI freezes of course while the PDF is calculated), I fixed this to get executed as background task, but I don't know if this really solve my customer issue.

Because even if I create a test database with millions of records, the app freezes of course for more than ten minutes, but my PDF is fine computed at the end.

So my actual problem is I would like to reproduce the issue of my customer. Is it possible I can't reproduce it as a real iPad Mini 1st Gen kills any app after the main thread is blocked for X minutes? If so is there a documentation anywhere?

Thanks, help is much appreciated!
Chuck

PS: I fear publishing my updated (background task instead of main thread) app will not solve the problem of my iPad Mini customer :(

Comment: You should ask for the crash report. This will help you to identify reason.

Comment: This is the very strange thing, that brought me to the idea the app does not crash, it just get's killed or something like that because of timeouts or something like that. Because of course I requested the crash logs. But the customer promised me there is no crash log in "Settings - Privacy - Diagnostics & usage - Diagnostics & usage Data" of my app.

Comment: It sounds more that a memory issue, the iOS watchdog is usually trigerred once you launch the application. Have you tried to use instruments and make a check on memory usage?

Comment: No, as I wrote, I'm not able to reproduce it. What could I do to simulate it? Could I limit memory on iOS simulator?

Comment: I believe this pointed me in the right direction, I noticed in iOS simulator the memory increases at the end of my calculations dramatically. I was able to remove this memory waste, and this makes also sense with the behavior on the old iPad with only 512 MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the memory usage pointed me in the right direction. I was able to solve the sudden memory increase (in my app) and I'm looking forward this will also solve the problem for my iPad Mini customer.

I identified this within Xcode Debug Navigator who shows the memory usage.